# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, but i HAVE something with that id

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and in my popup.js file I am getting an error that says

```
popup.js:17 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

What I am trying to do is execute a script when a button is clicked in popup.html.

```
// var app = chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage();

function alert() {
       chrome.tabs.executeScript({
       file: 'alert.js'
});
}
function saveit(){
       chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'save.js'
});
}

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', alert);
document.getElementById("savebutton").addEventListener('click', saveit);
```

I have two buttons on my page, with the exact same code for both. The first one with id button works and the second one with id savebutton doesn't and returns the error. I read on google and stack overflow that it it could be because I am getting an element with an id that doesnt exist, but I do have the right id.
The two tags are

`<button id="button">CLICK ME</button>`
and

```
<button id="savebutton">THIS</button>
```

I don't know what it could be. Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT-- Fixed it. I had to put the script tag after the button in the html code. I guess it was running the script before the button was created.

Comment: Have you shared the full code? Are you absolutely sure you aren't changing the ID somewhere else with a setAttribute or similar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: No i'm not changing the id anywhere. i don't even know how to do that haha.

Comment: Thank you for the link but as you can see in my edit I solved the problem. Thank you anyway though!